# Running cable through vapor barrier

Tags: vapor-barrier, crawlspace, cabling

I have a manufactured home (2001 vintage) sitting on a crawlspace. (I.e. it has mortared cinderblocks around it rather than skirting.) The home has a vapor barrier attached to the underside between it and the crawlspace. I want to run some ethernet cabling through the crawlspace. I'm planning to use the direct burial stuff and either just let it sit or bury it in the dirt floor of the crawlspace. I'm still working on building a drain to keep the crawlspace dry (I just bought the home and the previous owner saw no need to drain the crawlspace) so I want the vapor barrier to stay intact. Is there any way to run cable through the barrier and seal around it so that it's not letting moisture or cold air through?

Comment: I doubt the barrier is perfect enough so that you'd notice the effect of a couple of small holes in it. If so, then a good quality duct tape might do the job (depending on the vapor barrier material).

Comment: I agree with Daniel but I would use RTV to seal the hole as tape usually fails with wires in my experiance.

Comment: [Room temperature vulcanization (RTV) silicone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTV_silicone).

Comment: @EdBeal Using acronyms is not that useful on a DIY site where most users (especially askers) are not trade professionals.

Comment: @DanielGriscom that's what the guys who hooked up my phone+internet seemed to think (that it wasn't going to matter if they poked a 3/4" hole in the vapor barrier) but their job was to get me a good internet connection, not keep my house dry. On the other hand I'm also in a very rural area and I've already had to deal with one mouse so I don't feel like inviting other critters in through holes.

Comment: @EdBeal seems like a tricky job to keep the wire and sheeting from shifting while the silicone is setting and messing up the seal. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DanielGriscom can you turn your comment into an answer please?

Comment: @EdBeal can you turn your comment into an answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Griscom said (in a comment):

> I doubt the barrier is perfect enough so that you'd notice the effect
>   of a couple of small holes in it. If so, then a good quality duct tape
>   might do the job (depending on the vapor barrier material).

I agree with Daniel, but I would use RTV (room temperature Vulcanization) to seal the hole as tape usually fails with wires in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I have been given two suggestions elsewhere:

1. seal the vapor barrier around the cable with construction seaming tape (which is used for patching vapor barriers)
2. Clamp or staple barrier and cable to the joist at the point where the cable passes through, and add spray foam.

I'm going to build little jigs to test the durability of both solutions as well as what was suggested here and will update this answer when I know for sure what I'm doing.