# is there anything wrong with using plastic sheeting under joists in a dirt crawlspace area?

Tags: crawlspace, vapor-barrier

background info: old farm house crawlspace with exterior perimeter walls made from boulders and cement skimmed to create a fall surface. joists under the main living space have batting type fiberglass insulation. forced air heat from metal ductwork. wood stove in living area for main heat during winter.

we are planning a furnace replacement project and adding an air conditioning unit.
we are planning on also replacing the existing round metal ductwork with insulated flexible ductwork for better efficiency for heating and cooling.

when doing research, reading articles at buildingscience.com, and some youtube videos, the usage of plastic sheeting as a vapor barrier is shown on the dirt floor.

I don't understand why you would care about that "space" if you're not living in it, and I just want to add a vapor barrier to the joists, to help slowdown the movement of air from the crawlspace area into the living area, and help hold the insulation up too.

since the outside air comes into the crawlspace (it is not air tight) I think it is a waste to put a plastic vapor barrier on the dirt floor.

is there anything wrong with using 10 mil plastic sheeting on the bottom of the joists in this type of application? I don't foresee it trapping any moisture in that area, since this old farm house has plenty of mystery gaps in it where air moves around.

this post mentions existing plastic vapor barrier on the underside of the joists of a manufactured home. [Running cable through vapor barrier](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/80804/running-cable-through-vapor-barrier)

also, since there is existing insulation, there doesn't seem to be much of an extra advantage of using polyfoam 4x8 sheets as a barrier, and they would need to be cut into thin strips to be able to be moved into the crawlspace area. and the joist distances are not all equal so that will add extra capacity.

any feedback is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: A breathable house wrap may be a better option

Comment: Is the home air conditioned?

Comment: Vapour barrier is placed on dirt floors to prevent moisture/damp from coming up.  It is also used on inside of exterior walls to prevent moisture going into insulation. Vapour barrier under joists would hold moisture/damp in floor insulation.

Comment: Here's one problem with what you're suggesting.  In the summer, the humidity in your house is going to be high, even with AC.  Your crawlspace probably stays close to 50 deg or 55 deg (F) year round.  When that relatively warm air from your house migrates through the floor and comes in contact with the cool plastic what's going to happen? That's right, condensation.  So now you have water sitting on the top of your plastic, a perfect breeding ground for mold.  Far better to try and keep the moisture out.

Comment: aha, that is a good point about the plastic trapping moisture / condensation and allowing mold to grow. thanks. we will reconsider.